# Cannot set static IP address using Netsh

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, sql-server, netsh

I have followed [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/MCSA+70-462/103881/) article to set the following environment:

[image]

- DC: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (Full Installation) - Domain
  controller for the lab network, contoso.com
- SQL-A: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (Full Installation) - Domain
  member for hosting SQL Server
- SQL-B: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise  (Full Installation) -
  Domain member for hosting SQL Server
- SQL-C: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (Full Installation) - Domain
  member for hosting SQL Server
- SQL-D: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (Full Installation) - Domain
  member for hosting SQL Server
- SQL-CORE: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (Server Core
  Installation) - Domain member for hosting SQL Server

Now I have to executing the following command on the DC machine:

```
Netsh interface ipv4 set address “Local Area Connection” static 10.10.10.10
```

but I get error:

> Element not found.

I have not got any experience with windows administration and was not able to solve the error googling it.

Could anyone tell what is causing the issue?

Comment: Add mask and gateway as follows: `... static 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.1`

Comment: Weird double quotation marks `“”` in the [`66-99`style](http://imglop.com/quotation-marks.asp): left `“` 66-styled `U+201C` and right `”` 99-styled `U+201D`. Use both simple `"` U+0022 instead. And the `"Local Area Connection"` should be the same as `ipconfig` displays as an adapter name .

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. It turns out that during the setup of my VM, I had multiple LAN connections created (I created mine in VirtualBox) and I ended up deleting the one named "Local Area Connection." My active connection was named "Local Area Connection 2."

I discovered this by running the command: `netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces`

Then I ran the original `netsh` command with the interface number instead of the name and it worked.

See [here for original source of answer.](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/26443-41-help-assigning-virtual-server-hyper)